# jquery-UI Drag + clone div inside other div and make it sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, clone, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to create a situation where it is possible to drag and clone a div inside another div multiple times, this div in the specific container has tot be sortable with the other ones.

```
$(function() {
    $( ".drag" ).each(function(){
        $(this).draggable({
            helper: "clone"
        });
    });

    $( ".day " ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var targetElem = $(this).attr("id");

            $( this ).addClass( "" );
            if($(ui.draggable).hasClass('draggable-source'))
                $( ui.draggable ).clone().appendTo( this ).removeClass('draggable-source');
            else
                $( ui.draggable ).appendTo( this );

            console.log(this.id)
        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "div",
        sort: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
        }
    });
});
```

This is working in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mfUCe/

This is where i got stuck:
I want to be able to drag the 2 divs in to the divs that are already inside of the droppable containers.

it would be great if anybody could help me